# Can someone help me figure out what this code does?

Tags: hyperref

The following code is from our universities thesis template, which is not very well documented, and as I'm the most skilled LaTeX user, and I'm a middling user at best, we don't know what a lot of the code in it does. Could someone help us figure out what this macro does? I can tell that it has something to do with `hyperref`, but beyond that we don't know. It is right above a bunch of code for modifying `csthesis` to add a List of Programs, so it could have something to do with that?

Is there enough here to tell what it is doing?

Oh and no, I can't post up a MWE as we don't know what it does, and it was taken out of an entire Ph.D. thesis.

```
\makeatletter
\def\contentsline#1#2#3#4{%
  \ifx\\#4\\%
    \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
  \else
    \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
      \hyper@linkstart{link}{#4}{#2}\hyper@linkend
    }{%
      % same link destination for the page:
      \hyper@linkstart{link}{#4}{#3}\hyper@linkend
      % link destination is the page itself:
      % \hyperpage{#3}%
    }%
  \fi
} \makeatother
```

(I'm hoping there is enough code there, this is sitting off by itself in the template so I'm hoping it is self contained. I'm also hoping this is not too localized.)

Comment: it defines contentline (that adds a section to the table of contents) using the standard or hyperref version depending if #4 is empty if #1 is (say) `subsection` the core of it runs `\l@subsection` which article defies as `\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2.3em}}`

Comment: It seems that the class wants to do what `hyperref` does better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In older versions of `hyperref` either the titles or the page numbers could be made a link, not both. Therefore the definition of `\contentsline` in the question modifies the old definition of `hyperref`'s `\contentsline` to add a link to both the title and the page number.

Since version 2008/04/13 6.77n `hyperref` has a new option `linktoc`. From
`hyperref`'s [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf):

> ### Option `linktoc` added
>
> The new option `linktoc` allows more control which part
>   of an entry in the table of contents is made into a link:
>
> - `linktoc=none`    (no links)
> - `linktoc=section` (default behaviour, same as `linktocpage=false`)
> - `linktoc=page`    (same as `linktocpage=true`)
> - `linktoc=all`     (both the section and page part are links)

With an up-to-date `hyperref` you can delete the definition of `\contentsline` and use

```
\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}[2008/04/13]
```

The option can also be set via `\hypersetup`.

Comment: What is that date at the end for?

Comment: @Canageek: It is the minimal required version of the package. Since 2008/04/13 option `linktoc` is available.

Comment: So probably not needed, but a good idea.

Comment: @Canageek: You get a better error message from LaTeX, if the `hyperref` version is too old.